# Gnu regex fails if `size` parameter of getline is not reset to 0

Tags: c, regex, getline

The code below consist of `read_files()` that reads a bunch of text files and `match()` function that does string matching against a pattern using the gnu regex library.

inside `read_files()` i use `getline()` with `size` argument set to 0 so that `getline()` will start with the default 120 size and then increased as needed

```
#include <limits.h> // for PATH_MAX
#include <regex.h>  // for regcomp, regerror, regexec, regfree, size_t, REG...
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf, fprintf, NULL, fclose, fopen, getline
#include <stdlib.h> // for exit, free, EXIT_FAILURE

int match(const char *regex_str, const char *str) {

    regex_t regex;
    int reti;
    char msgbuf[100];

    /* Compile regular expression */
    reti = regcomp(&regex, regex_str, REG_EXTENDED);
    if (reti) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Execute regular expression */
    reti = regexec(&regex, str, 0, NULL, 0);
    if (!reti) {
        return 1;
    } else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Free memory allocated to the pattern buffer by regcomp() */
    regfree(&regex);
}

void read_files() {

    size_t path_count = 2;
    char pathnames[2][PATH_MAX] = {"./tmp/test0.conf", "./tmp/test1.conf"};

    FILE *fp;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read_count;

    for (int i = 0; i < path_count; i++) {
        printf("opening file %s\n", pathnames[i]);

        fp = fopen(pathnames[i], "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("internal error,couldn't open file %s\"}", pathnames[i]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        int linenum=1;
        while ((read_count = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
            printf("%d: %s",linenum,line);
            linenum++;
        }
        printf("len: %zu\n", len);

        fclose(fp);
        // len=0; // this is the line that fixes the bug, if i reset len to 0 after reading the first file then everything works as expected, if i don't reset it then regex matching fails
        if (line)
            free(line);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    read_files();

    if (!match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", "jack")) {
        printf("input don't match\n");
    }
}
```

the content of test0.conf

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

the content of test1.conf

```
testing123
```

when running the above code i get this output:

```
opening file ./tmp/test0.conf
1: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
len: 240
opening file ./tmp/test1.conf
1: testing123
len: 240
input don't match
```

so the pattern matching is failing with the string "jack" which in reality matches.

You can see that after finishing reading the first file that `len` is set to 240 so when `getline` gets executed again for the second file it will read the file with `240` buffer size, but this for some reason causes the regex matching to fail.

If i reset the `len` to 0 argument after reading the first file then the code works as expected(the regex matching works fine).

So why does the `getline()` `len` parameter affect the behavior of the gnu regex?

Comment: Most probably, the trailing newline is a culprit. Chomp the line before applying the regex validation.

Comment: getline's second argument holds the size which was allocated for the line, not the actual length of the line. The actual length of the line is the return value of 'getline', and you store it in 'read_count' variable.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the newline where ? do you mean in the lines read from the files? if you look closely at the last lines of the main function, you can see I'm calling the `match` function with string literals I'm not using anything that was read from the files so no newline characters exist in the string to be matched.

Comment: @Marian I'm aware of what you said, but what does this have to do with my bug?

Comment: 'getline' is supposed to be called multiple times with the same arguments and reusing previous allocated string. If you do not set the 'len' to 0 and you free 'line' between two successives calls of 'getline', 'getline' does not realized the string was freed and it writes the second line into freed memory and corrupts the program. Normally you shall also set 'line' to NULL after having freed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So why does the getline() len parameter affect the behavior of the gnu regex?

As Marian commented, you are using `getline` incorrectly, causing it to corrupt heap. You can observe this by compiling the program with `-fsanitize=address` flag and running it. See the [Address Sanitizer manual](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) to understand the error.

This is undefined behavior, and your program can do *anything*. Here it just happens to cause the GNU regex library to stop working correctly. A `SIGSEGV` is another likely outcome.

To fix the problem, you should move the `free` call out of the loop and only free the memory after you are done reading the lines.

Setting `line = NULL` in the loop after you `free` it is another possible (but less efficient) fix.